# How to remove this old shower stem

Tags: plumbing

Father in law sent me on a mission. The inner nut to remove this stem broke off from age and now I have no clue how to get this stem out without tearing the wall out and yanking the whole valve out.

Help!

[image: Old shower stem]

Answer (score 0):

Get some CLR or vinegar and clean off the area where the nut goes into the valve base. Use a rotary tool (Dremel) with a cutoff wheel and cut three or four slots into the inner nut. Get a slotted screwdriver that just fits into a slot in the nut and tap the screwdriver with a hammer to try and turn the nut counterclockwise. Rotate around the nut using the different slots. Hopefully, this will eventually loosen the nut. You'll then need to get a new nut to attach the new/repaired valve stem. You can probably get one at a plumbing supply store, not your home store.

Another possibility would be to get a faucet spanner wrench similar to the one shown below that fits over the inner nut (picture from Delta Store). Use your rotary tool to cut two slots in the nut so the wrench fits into the slots and then turn the wrench counterclockwise to remove the nut.

[image]